Distribution of busy servers in a modified Erlang Loss system
Consider an $M/M/k/0$ queueing system (we have $k$ servers and if our system is already full, any clients will immediately leave). The arrival rate is $\lambda$ and the work rate is $\mu$. Now, let's say we have two types of clients - type A and type B. The probability that the client is type A is $p$. What is the distribution of the amount of type A clients in this system?
I know that the distribution for the amount of all clients is truncated Poisson, and it is quite obvious, that the arrival rate of type A clients is $p\lambda$. However, I feel that I can't just truncate Poisson by the amount of servers, not with the part of them being busy with type B clients. Truncating by $k-$(distribution of type B clients) is obviously not a solution.
I feel that I'm overthinking it. How can I find the distribution of type A clients?
